# What is equivalent of TOKEN_GENERATOR ORACLE SQL statement in SQLite

Tags: sql, sqlite, split, sql-like, recursive-query

I'm working with some SQL queries in ORACLE which have the following construct:

```
WITH TOKEN_GENERATOR AS (
    SELECT REGEXP_SUBSTR(:token_0, '[^,]+', 1, LEVEL) token
    FROM DUAL
    CONNECT BY LEVEL <= length(:token_0) - length(REPLACE(:token_0, ',', '')) + 1
)
```

where token_0 has comma separated binding values, e.g. `1,2,3,4`. This clause is used in conjunction with `SELECT` statements where it is referred as following:

```
WITH TOKEN_GENERATOR AS (
    SELECT REGEXP_SUBSTR(:token_0, '[^,]+', 1, LEVEL) token
    FROM DUAL
    CONNECT BY LEVEL <= length(:token_0) - length(REPLACE(:token_0, ',', '')) + 1
)
SELECT ... FROM ... WHERE T.COL in (SELECT TOKEN FROM TOKEN_GENERATOR)
```

My question is how to make a similar SQL statement in SQLite? Of course, I can replace `in` part of `SELECT` statement with something like `T.COL in (?,?,?.....)`, but what if the number of passed values is really large, e.g. in thousands. The `WITH TOKEN` statement allows `UNION` to battle this issue. The actual issue in ORACLE is described [here](https://betteratoracle.com/posts/20-how-do-i-bind-a-variable-in-list).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There is no equivalent functionality in SQLite.

One way to do what you want is with a recursive CTE which would split the comma separated list and return 1 row for each value:

```
WITH TOKEN_GENERATOR AS (
  SELECT '' token, '1,2,3' || ',' value 
  UNION ALL
  SELECT SUBSTR(value, 1, INSTR(value, ',') - 1),
         SUBSTR(value, INSTR(value, ',') + 1)
  FROM TOKEN_GENERATOR       
  WHERE LENGTH(value) > 1
)
SELECT token 
FROM TOKEN_GENERATOR
WHERE token <> ''
```

See the [demo](https://dbfiddle.uk/?rdbms=sqlite_3.27&fiddle=4d44b3b4ac2b89247d048eb95f25ead8).
Results:

| token |
| --- |
| 1 |
| 2 |
| 3 |

You can use it in your query like this:

```
WITH TOKEN_GENERATOR AS (
  SELECT '' token, :token_0 || ',' value 
  UNION ALL
  SELECT SUBSTR(value, 1, INSTR(value, ',') - 1),
         SUBSTR(value, INSTR(value, ',') + 1)
  FROM TOKEN_GENERATOR       
  WHERE LENGTH(value) > 1
)
SELECT ... FROM ... WHERE T.COL in (SELECT token FROM TOKEN_GENERATOR WHERE token <> '')
```

This would be ok if the list contains a few values, but for thousands of values I don't think that a recursive CTE would be the best choice, because what follows after the CTE is executed is the operator `IN` which again for thousands of rows will not perform good.

Another way to do what you want is with the operator `LIKE`:

```
SELECT ... FROM ... 
WHERE ',' || :token_0 || ',' LIKE '%,' || T.COL || ',%'
```

Answer (score 0):

You can use a recursive `WITH` clause:

```sql
WITH RECURSIVE tkn(value, e_pos) AS (
  SELECT 'a,b,c,d,e',
         INSTR('a,b,c,d,e', ',')
UNION ALL
  SELECT SUBSTR(value, e_pos + 1),
         INSTR( SUBSTR(value, e_pos + 1), ',' )
  FROM   tkn
  WHERE  e_pos > 0
)
SELECT CASE
       WHEN e_pos = 0
       THEN value
       ELSE SUBSTR( value, 1, e_pos - 1 )
       END AS VALUE
FROM   tkn;
```

Which outputs:

> | VALUE |
> | --- |
> | a |
> | b |
> | c |
> | d |
> | e |

*db<>fiddle [here](https://dbfiddle.uk/?rdbms=sqlite_3.27&fiddle=9171012bcc6b295fc327160d1917977a)*